# find tweets mentioning any arbitrary twitter user

Tags: twitter

For `statuses/mentions`, I need to authenticate as a user. I want to see the user's mentions without asking him/her to authenticate. If the tweets are public, what are the mentions not public ?

I'm writing to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693553/replies-to-a-particular-tweet-twitter-api)

Answer (score 7):

Check the Twitter search API
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html

To find all user mentions: just use @username as search term.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add that Twitter's Search API returns only tweets from past 7 days. So if you want to retrieve ALL tweets mentioning an arbitrary user, you can't.
If anyone finds a way to do this, please mention.

Comment: Thanks, can confirm, it only got me tweets not older than 9 days. I had to do a JavaScript workaround https://gist.github.com/elhardoum/c0c0fe3c41e7947a22417209f671b78d

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get a user's mentions using the statuses/mentions endpoint because this is possible using the search api.

http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search