# Getting twitter replies by using tweet id

Tags: php, twitter

I am developing an application and in this application I want to get "replies" tha belongs specific tweet. Is there any way to get replies of specified tweet by using ID?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replies to a particular tweet, Twitter API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693553/replies-to-a-particular-tweet-twitter-api)

Comment: Because of Twitter's internal architecture, there's no easy way to do this. Twitter does have a "summary" API that shows related info, which often includes mentions, but I think it's private. It's definitely not in the documentation.

Comment: Twitter doesn't response user email,  and second twitter doesn't give us tweet hierarchy. good news! Thanks for reply.

Comment: I think below link could help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693553/replies-to-a-particular-tweet-twitter-api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replies to a particular tweet, Twitter API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693553/replies-to-a-particular-tweet-twitter-api)