# Getting twitter replies

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to get replies (tweets) for a given tweet in twitter? I am searching for a API in twitter but couldn't find the same. Can some one help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Question is extremely general.  What language do you want to use?  If you type "twitter api" into google, it takes you to this walkthrough, did you read that?  https://dev.twitter.com/

Comment: It's not possible to fetch @ replies via a tweet ID. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693553/replies-to-a-particular-tweet-twitter-api

Comment: Maybe this repo can help you: https://github.com/ScrPzz/twitter_replies_scraper

Answer (score 2):

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/related_results/show/172019363942117377.json?include_entities=1
```

That is an experimental API.

By experimental API, this means that until we officially document it on dev.twitter.com, it's not necessarily production-ready and could be unstable both in the parameters it takes and the format of its responses. It also may just disappear one day.

As for related_results itself, it won't necessarily return every reply for a tweet nor are its responses necessarily limited to just replies. That said, for your own personal use or experimentation you may find some utility in the method. If you choose to use it in any software you're developing, I would proactively wrap its use with significant exception handling.

Comment: This call has been removed since API version 1 is no longer available.