# Get Twitter replies with LinqToTwitter

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I want to retrieve replies from a Tweet with LinqToTwitter api but i can`t.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840994/getting-twitter-replies) but it is already removed.

Some help?

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter API v1.0 introduced a related_results endpoint, but it didn't last long. Except for an initial blog on new API's at that time, it was undocumented. The answer, by Hassan Magdy, to the question you're linking to is accurate as well as it's follow-up comment.

LINQ to Twitter supports what the Twitter API offers. If the Twitter API doesn't support it, neither does LINQ to Twitter. In theory you might approach this task by looking at the user's home timeline to find tweets that reply to a given tweet. However, you would encounter limitations through rate limits, the need to be authorized as the original tweeter, and miss parts of a conversation from people who are not friends or followers of the original tweeter. This would require a significant amount of resources and complex code and still not be 100% accurate.

Comment: I found `StatusType.Conversation` in LinqToTwitter (and even a demo), isn't it for getting replies? I tied to use it but getting TwitterQueryException: "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource". Could comment.

Comment: I don't remember how, but found that endpoint (conversation/show.json) at one time. Now it isn't documented. Though I left the code in place, I have no knowledge on whether that endpoint exists or not.