# reading Twitter replies windows phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, twitter, hammock

I am relatively new to windows phone app development. I am building a twitter based application and trying to read replies to a specific tweet.Been trying to do it hard without any luck :( i am using hammock api.

a discussion at this link https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/293 shows that we can do it with version 1 of twitter api which is now deprecated.

[Replies to a particular tweet, Twitter API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693553/replies-to-a-particular-tweet-twitter-api) this link also shows a similar solution in version 1 but nothing for 1.1. I am able to post,retweet but not able to read replies.Looking for any version 1.1 solutions. Thanks.