# Get all replies of a particular tweet using API Twitter

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using the Twitter API in a Swift application, I want to show a particular tweet along with all of its replies, How can I do it?

I saw many old posts that say "there is no way to retrieve the replies of a tweet", Has it changed? is there a way to do that now? 
 [example of post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693553/replies-to-a-particular-tweet-twitter-api)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replies to a particular tweet, Twitter API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693553/replies-to-a-particular-tweet-twitter-api)