# Get count of reply to a particular tweets

Tags: python, twitter, twitter4j, tweepy, twython

I am using the Python `tweepy` library.

I was successfully able to extract the 'liked' and 're-tweet' counts of a tweet using the below code:

```
# Get count of handles who are following you
def get_followers_count(handle):
    user = api.get_user(handle)
    return user.followers_count

# Get count of handles that you are following
def get_friends_count(handle):
    user = api.get_user(handle)
    return user.friends_count

# Get count of tweets for a handle
def get_status_count(handle):
    user = api.get_user(handle)
    return user.statuses_count

# Get count of tweets liked by user
def get_favourite_count(handle):
    user = api.get_user(handle)
    return user.favourits_count
```

**However, I couldn't find a way to get the reply counts of a particular tweet.**

Is it possible to get reply count of a tweet using tweepy or any other library like twython or even twitter4j?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693553/4764434

Comment: I request you to please remove duplicate tag, as this answer if very old

Comment: Reopening, but there hasn't been much change, I'll let others decide to keep this open or close.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replies to a particular tweet, Twitter API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693553/replies-to-a-particular-tweet-twitter-api)

Comment: @Zero I think you were right - I voted to close too .

Answer (score 2):

The example code below shows how you could implement a solution to finding all replies for a single tweet. It utilizes the twitter search operator `to:<account>` and grabs all tweets that have replies to that account. By using `since_id=tweet_id`, the tweets returned from `api.search` are restricted to those created after the time the post was created. After these tweets are obtained, the `in_reply_to_status_id` attribute is used to check if the tweet captured is a reply to the tweet of interest.

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET_KEY)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

user = 'MollyNagle3'
tweet_id = 1368278040300650497
t = api.search(q=f'to:{user}', since_id=tweet_id,)

replies = 0
for i in range(len(t)):

    if t[i].in_reply_to_status_id == tweet_id:
        replies += 1
print(replies)
```

The limitation of this code is that is inefficient. It grabs more tweets than necessary. However, it seems that it is the best way to do this. Also, if you want to get replies of a very old tweet, you can implement the parameter `max_id` in api.search to limit the length of time you search over for replies.