# Reply a Tweet Only One Time

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using Twitter API and PHP to reply a specific tweet.

For example. If another user mentions me like "@Diga reply me!" I'm replying them. Otherwise, I just discard the mention.

This is a basic if statement and I could handle this. The problem is, when another user mentions me and I run the script again, scripts replies both of them because there is already another mention.

```
$statues = $connection->get("statuses/mentions_timeline");

if(count($statues)>0)
{
    $message= strtolower($statues[0]->text);
    $message= trim(str_replace("@diga","",$message));
    if($message== "reply me!")
    {
        $user_name = "@".trim($statues[0]->user->screen_name);
        $tweetID = $statues[0]->id_str;
        $statues = $connection->post("statuses/update", ["status" => $user_name." I can reply you!", "in_reply_to_status_id" => $tweetID]);
    }
}
else
{
    echo "no mention.";
}
```

In this code, if there are any mentions, scripts starts checking the messages. Actually, I'm only checking one mention (0) because of testing. But still, I want to reply this tweet only 1 time. After that, even if I run this script, I don't want it to reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have **multiple** ways to do that :

1. Use a **database** to store the **ID** of the tweets you already have replied and
   ignore those where the ID is already in the database.
2. **If your script run
   automatically** every 10 minutes, only reply to mentions from tweets
   sent in the last 10 minutes.
3. [Look if you have already replied to
   the tweet.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693553/replies-to-a-particular-tweet-twitter-api)

Comment: couldn't handle last 2 but I did accomplish by using a database.