# In python, how we extract the replies from each tweet twitter API?

Tags: python, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am trying to extract the replies of each tweets from twitter but I can't find the way to do. Now, I can authenticate a twitter API.
[Authenticated API image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4o1N.png)

[Authenticated API response/output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jdPa.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replies to a particular tweet, Twitter API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693553/replies-to-a-particular-tweet-twitter-api)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jarimjim welcome to stackoverflow.

For Authentication below code will help you because you're using **tweepy**

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

//Example to test authentication.
public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
```

Now if you want to get all **retweets** by other you can do try this.

```
API.retweets_of_me([since_id][, max_id][, count][, page])
```

Returns the 20 most recent tweets of the authenticated user that have been retweeted by others.

**Parameters:**

- since_id – Returns only statuses with an ID greater than (that is,
  more recent than) the specified ID.
- max_id – Returns only statuses with an ID less than (that is, older
  than) or equal to the specified ID.
- count – The number of results to try and retrieve per page.
- page – Specifies the page of results to retrieve. Note: there are
  pagination limits.

**Return type:**
list of `Status` objects

> All these things are extracted from http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/
>
> How to get consumer key and secret visit this [link](https://support.yapsody.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003291573-How-do-I-get-a-Twitter-Consumer-Key-and-Consumer-Secret-key-)
>
> How to get access token and access secret visit this [link](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/guides/authenticating-users)