# Is it possible to use the Twitter API to get replies older than 7 days?

Tags: twitter

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693553/replies-to-a-particular-tweet-twitter-api), but the answers are a bit of a mess: outdated, focused on various libraries' capabilities, and/or not clear about whether they apply to old tweets.

I'm trying to look up replies to historical tweets (months or years old). I want to know if it's theoretically possible to use the Twitter API to directly or indirectly find those replies. At first glance, the `conversation_id` introduced in v2 seems intended for things like this, but the only way I've found to use it is in the [recent search endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-recent), which only goes back 7 days. This is nearly useless for me.

The closest I've got is to look up tweets from the original author's timeline and look for ones in the same conversation. But that's limited to their most recent 3,200 tweets, and won't find replies from other people.

FYI, I'm only interested in the endpoints available to the general public for free, not the Academic or Enterprise ones. I think this is called the Standard product track (Basic access level).

Comment: It might be worth noting that Enterprise access was available for as low as $150/mo as of a few years ago: https://techcrunch.com/2017/11/14/twitter-launches-lower-cost-subscription-access-to-its-data-through-new-premium-apis/